# Full screen mode with flex air on Windows

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, air, fullscreen

My application can go into fullscreen mode.
But it always 'opens' behind Windows Media Center, and I need my air app to display above the media center.

I found this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb189148.aspx
At the overlaying part it says "It is not possible to overlay anything other than a dialog box or a prompt over the Windows Media Center full-screen video experience."

I assume I might need to write a C# app to display a dialog over the media center?
Any other ideas are much appreciated.

My code:

```
this.stage.nativeWindow.activate();
this.stage.nativeWindow.restore();
this.stage.nativeWindow.maximize();

stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set alwaysInFront property of NativeWindow to true

Comment: alwaysInFront is true, it helps to keep it above all the other explorer windows and applications, just not windows media center for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I have a dual screen Air app (AS3 project) and I ran media center (Windows 7) at full screen then ran my app. My app opens focused.

Here are some of my settings, hope this helps.

Main Stage:

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
```

Pop screen:

```
with(popScreenOptions){
    type = NativeWindowType.NORMAL;
    minimizable = false;            
    resizable = false;
    maximizable = false;
    systemChrome = NativeWindowSystemChrome.NONE;
    transparent = false;
}
```

Comment: Hi @NoelLastrella, thx for the reply.
Am I correct if I say the following: When air app has focus, it will go into fullscreen above media center, and when media center has focus, media center will display above the air app.

I just tested it: 
1) open media center (window mode)
2) run a .bat file that will open air app after 5 sec
3) go into full screen mode with media center
4) air app opens behind media center

Comment: When I exit the 'game mode' when media center is in full screen mode, the air app displays above media center.

game mode - when it first goes into fullscreen, it opens like a 'game', when you press 'Alt + Tab' just to 'exit' that mode. It stays full screen, just not above everything, the taskbar at the bottom is visible.

I assume you have it in the same 'mode' for your app? Maybe you changed some startup settings for media center?

Thx again!